# Can't add ESB Registry Resource to CAR file for deployment

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a ESB Registry Project with several resources (WSDLs, XSDs, etc) and have been deploying applications to WSO2 ESB including some resources in the project.

Now all my other projects (some ESB configs and BPELs) that had any dependency on that registry project can't be deployed anymore because eclipse can't add the resources to the CAR file anymore. When I open the export wizard and try to check which resources are being added to the CAR file I get this:

["forbidden" resources in my CAR file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoXkk.png)

It looks like the whole registry project got invalid of some reason, and know I cant add any resource in that project to any other CAR file.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For unknown reason Eclipse have corrupted the artifact.xml file for the registry resource project, so all registry resources under the project became unavailable. I closed Eclipse and modified artifact.xml file manually and it went back to normal.